# Recursive call messes up rendering in game

Tags: javascript, recursion, processing

I have the following code (ignore that `sleep` thing:

```
function game_loop(snake){
    sleep(200);

    background(200);
    draw_borders();

    const r = snake_draw(snake_move(snake.x, snake.y));
    game_loop(r);
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(w, h);
    frameRate(10);
    noLoop();
}

function draw() {
    game_loop({x: snake_initial_x, y: snake_initial_y});
}

function sleep(delay) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}

function snake_move(x, y){
    const x_speed = 1;
    const y_speed = 0;

    return {x: x + x_speed, y: y + y_speed };
}

function snake_draw(position){
    const snake_color = 255 ;

    fill(snake_color);
    rect(position.x * sqr_size, position.y * sqr_size, sqr_size, sqr_size);

    return position;
};

const border_color = 81;

function draw_borders(){
    draw_row_borders(0);
    draw_column_borders(1);
}

function draw_row_borders(x){
    if(x >= 0 && x < cols) {
        fill(border_color);
        rect(x * sqr_size, 0, sqr_size, sqr_size);
        fill(border_color);
        rect(x * sqr_size, (rows - 1) * sqr_size, sqr_size, sqr_size);

        draw_row_borders(x + 1, 0);
    }
}

function draw_column_borders(y){
    if(y >= 1 && y < rows - 1) {
        fill(border_color);
        rect(0, y * sqr_size, sqr_size, sqr_size);
        fill(border_color);
        rect((cols - 1) * sqr_size,  y * sqr_size, sqr_size, sqr_size);

        draw_column_borders(y + 1);
    } 
}
```

The last parts of the code are not needed, but I add them just in case.

My problem is that when I call `game_loop(r)` or `game_loop(snake_draw(snake_move(snake.x, snake.y)))`, the game stops rendering everything, but if I put a `console.log()` inside `game_loop`, I can see that it's working (i.e, calling the function, updating `snake.x, snake.y`).

Why does this recursive call mess everything up?

I'm using the p5js framework, by the way.

Comment: Usually JavaScript code is event based (i.e. timer events) and not using busy wait... There is a good chance that framework you are using have an example of writing game loop with timer...

Comment: The framework only calls `draw()` 60 times a second, **unless** `noLoop()` was called (which I did call), and then draw is only called once. The `game_loop()` I wrote has nothing to do with it!

Comment: If `game_loop()` (infinite recursion) has nothing to do with your code why you've included it in the post? (Also `game_loop` is called from your `draw` - not sure how it can "has nothing to do with it")

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Sorry, I phrased that poorly, I meant that the framework only calls draw and setup once (and provides drawing tools), but nothing more, the game_loop function is not related with the way the framework acts.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out? If so you might want to upvote and accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript and the browser's drawing mechanisms are tightly coupled in a single thread. If your javascript loops for too long, it blocks the drawing process and essentially hangs the browser.

In most game frameworks, there is an `update()` function of some sort that gets called once per "frame". This can be done in a variety of ways such as using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) or [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) which call a function after a specific number of milliseconds.

```js
function update() {
    console.log('updated');
}

// call update function every 100 milliseconds 
setInterval(update, 100);
```

If you want a slightly more functional approach, you can recursively call `setTimeout()` instead.

```js
function update() {
  console.log('updated');
  // perform game logic here
  setTimeout(update, 500); // call update again in 500 milliseconds
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, `snake_draw()` is called before the recursive call to `game_loop()`, why isn't `game_loop()` called AFTER the drawing is done, but before it? Also, I understand that this is most likely done using things like `setInterval()`, but I'm trying to make my game in a functional programming style.

Comment: Well, it's the functional way of writing a game_loop, isn't it? How else would I update the game parameters, without mutable state?

Comment: It is one method of doing loops in functional programming, but what you're after isn't really possible. Recursion, for loops and while loops all block. If they're made infinite, they'll loop forever and never give the browser a moment to redraw. Browsers have an event loop in them already, part of which is a redrawing or "layout" phase.

Comment: @csTroubled from theoretical point of view you probably right... but you also observe matching result - function produces the same result (infinite recursion without any visible effects :) ) irrespective when you call it. Boundary between real world and pure functions is always rough... Also I don't see why scheduling next iteration of the loop with parameters captured in closure with `setInterval(iteration_with_captured_parameters, 100)` is not functional way...

Answer (score 1):

To get "functional style" - capture parameters for next iteration and schedule it with `setInterval`:

```
function game_loop(r) {
     // draw r
     r = nextStep(r); // compute next immutable state

     var next_iteration = function(){ 
        game_loop(r); // capture state 
     } 
     setInterval(next_iteration, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Processing calls the `draw()` function for you automatically, 60 times per second. Each call to the `draw()` function is a **frame**, and that's where you should put your game logic.

You seem to be trying to create your own game loop, which is unnecessary and will break what Processing already does automatically for you.

**The `draw()` function needs to finish before anything is actually drawn to the screen.**

You're preventing the `draw()` function from finishing, so nothing is drawn to the screen. At the beginning of the program, you're calling the `game_loop()` function. But from the `game_loop()` function, you then call the `game_loop()` function, which calls the `game_loop()` function, which.... this goes on indefinitely, so you never get past the first frame!

More generally, what you're doing is called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion), and you're missing a **base case** (something that stops the recursion from going on forever). It won't actually go on forever, since you'll eventually get a stack overflow - the error, not this website!

To fix your problem, you either need to add a base case that prevents your recursion from going on forever, or better yet, just get rid of it! Processing already calls the `draw()` function for you 60 times per second, so use that for your draw loop.

**Edit:** Looking a little closer, maybe you're trying to use recursion to draw your snake by drawing individual sections and then recursing to the next section? If so, then you just need a **base case** by incrementing the section you're looking at and then checking that the section is still in the snake.

**Edit 2:** The answers telling you to call `setInterval()` **might** work (although I wouldn't be surprised if it causes problems with Processing's internal mechanisms), but there really is no point in doing that. Processing already sets up a game loop for you. Just use that.

Comment: Note that OP clearly knows about default behavior of `draw` called automatically ([comment to Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157713/recursive-call-messes-up-rendering-in-game/39158047#comment65659002_39157713)), but looking for functional style with immutable data ([comment on other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157713/recursive-call-messes-up-rendering-in-game/39158047#39158047))

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good point. I've edited my answer. Thanks for the heads up.